# Ошибка при API запросе

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, telegram, api

Запускаю телеграм бот, работу он не прекращает, но в Телеграм приходит сообщение

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const token = 'Токен телеграма';
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {
    polling: true
});

bot.onText(/\/start/, (msg) => {
    const { id } = msg.chat;

    exec(
        'curl -H "твой_действительный_токен" https://direct.lptracker.ru/lead/103451/list?offset=10&limit=1&sort[updated_at]=3&filter[created_at_from]=1535529725',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                bot.sendMessage(id, `Ошибка выполнения запроса: ${error.message}`);
                return;
            }
            if (stderr) {
                bot.sendMessage(id, `Ошибка выполнения запроса: ${stderr}`);
                return;
            }
            bot.sendMessage(id, `Результат запроса:\n${stdout}`);
        }
    );
});
```

```
Ошибка выполнения запроса: Command failed: curl -H "Токен моего телеграма" https://direct.lptracker.ru/lead/103451/list?offset=10&limit=1&sort[updated_at]=3&filter[created_at_from]=1535529725
```